# Extracting symbols from the ellipsis argument of a function in a referentially transparent manner

Tags: r

It's happened again. A question that I was just about to push the button for posting an answer was deleted:

I'm looking for a way to extract from the ellipsis argument of a function the values of objects which are bound to symbols, as well as symbols. That is, I'm trying to extract symbols from the ellipsis in a referentially transparent manner. I've tried playing around with substitute and lazy_dots and haven't had success.

```
 # function I'm trying to create
 get_symbols <- function(...) {
     # insert code here
     # should return a character vector of symbols
 }

# example function calls
some_function <- function(...){
    get_symbols(...)
}

z <- quote(T)
some_function(quote(x), ~y, z)
# should return vector of symbols c(x, ~y, T)

some_function(quote(x), ~y, quote(T))
# should return vector of symbols c(x, ~y, T)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if these uses of `substitute` and `deparse` are helpful. The `deparse` function return text/character vectors from (valid) language expressions. :

```
 some_function1 <- function(...){
         print(sapply( substitute(list(...)), deparse)[-1]) # -1 drops "list"
     }

     z <- quote(T)
     some_function1(quote(x), ~y, z)
#[1] "quote(x)" "~y"       "z"       
     some_function1(quote(x), ~y, quote(T))
#[1] "quote(x)" "~y"       "quote(T)"
```

This version evaluates its arguments which might be the second part of what was desired, namely the values:

```
 some_function2 <- function(...){
         print(sapply(list(...), deparse))
     }

     z <- quote(T)
     some_function2(quote(x), ~y, z)
#[1] "x"  "~y" "T" 
     some_function2(quote(x), ~y, quote(T))
#[1] "x"  "~y" "T"
```