# Replace one symbol in an expression with multiple values

Tags: r, metaprogramming, static-code-analysis

Given an arbitrary fixed expression, I want to substitute a single symbol with a collection of multiple values. Examples:

```
Expression       | Symbol | Replace with               | Desired Output
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
f(x, 5)          | x      | a = 1, b = sym, c = "char" | f(a = 1, b = sym, c = "char", 5)
g(f(h(y)), z)    | y      | 1, 2, 3                    | g(f(h(1, 2, 3)), z)
g(f(h(y), z), z) | z      | 4, x                       | g(f(h(y), 4, x), 4, x)
```

The `substitute()` function comes close, but it is not exactly what I am looking for. In the example below, I want to turn `f(x)` into `f(1, b = 4, c = d)`, but I have not yet found the right `env` argument.

```r
substitute(
  expr = f(x),
  env = list(x = list(1, b = 4, c = rlang::sym("d")))
)
#> f(list(1, b = 4, c = d))

substitute(
  expr = f(x),
  env = list(x = as.call(c(quote(x), 1, b = 4, c = quote(d)))[-1])
)
#> f(1(b = 4, c = d))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Is it possible to find an `env` such that `substitute(f(x), env)` equals `f(1, b = 4, c = d)`?

Remarks:

- Above, it is important that we begin with `f(x)`. We cannot simply write `as.call(c(quote(f), env))`.
- The motivating use case is described at https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/724 and https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/726.
- We cannot use `!!!` from tidy evaluation because all tidy evaluation in [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) needs to be handled separately.
- This post replaces [an earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602461/base-r-alternative-to-tidy-evals) that was less clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a take on a splicing function

```
splice <- function(x, replacements) {
  if (is(x, "call")) {
    as.call(do.call("c",lapply(as.list(x), splice, replacements), quote=T))
  } else if (is(x, "name")) {
    if (deparse(x) %in% names(replacements)) {
      return(replacements[[deparse(x)]])
    } else {
      list(x)
    }
  } else {
    list(x)
  }
}
```

It seems to work with the sample input

```
splice(quote(f(x, 5) ), list(x=list(a = 1, b = quote(sym), c = "char" )))
# f(a = 1, b = sym, c = "char", 5)
splice(quote(g(f(h(y)), z)) , list(y=list(1,2,3)))
# g(f(h(1, 2, 3)), z)
splice(quote(g(f(h(y), z), z)), list(z=list(4, quote(x))) )
# g(f(h(y), 4, x), 4, x)
```

Basically you just swap out the symbol names. it should also work with single variable replacements that aren't in a list.

```
splice(quote(f(x,5)), list(x=7))
# f(7, 5)
```

You basically need to re-write the call by manipulating it as a list. This is what the tidyverse functions are doing behind the scene. They intercept the current call, re-write it, then evaluate the newly expanded call. `substitute` will never work because you aren't just replacing one symbol with one value. You need to change the number of parameters you are passing to a function.

Comment: Thanks so much, @MrFlick! Glad I know about `do.call(quote = TRUE)` now.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is clunky, but (I think) it does what you need; it was inspired by (and one line taken from) [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29201866/8386140) to a somewhat related post:

```
multi_substitute <- function(expr, key, ...) {
    expr <- deparse(substitute(expr))
    key <- deparse(substitute(key))
    # The following line is the bit I got from the mentioned SO answer
    l <- sapply( substitute(list(...)), deparse)[-1] 
    l <- paste(names(l), l, sep = " = ")
    l <- sub("^ = ", "", l)
    l <- paste(l, collapse = ",")
    vals <- deparse(substitute(...))
    result <- sub(key, l, expr)
    return(parse(text = result)[[1]])
}
multi_substitute(f(x), x, 1, b = 4, c = quote(d))
# f(1, b = 4, c = quote(d))
```

You might be able to get this a little more elegant or tailor it to better suit your needs.

If you don't want to force provision of the `key` argument there, you could of course change that around pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I would rather avoid text replacement. Deparsing and parsing are slow, and text replacement has edge cases. For example, `multi_substitute(f(not_x, x), x, 1, b = 4, c = quote(d))` equals `f(not_1, b = 4, c = quote(d), x)` instead of the desired `f(not_x, 1, b = 4, c = quote(d))`.